# finviewbyid return null using multisupportscreen

Tags: android

So the problem is in my layout I think. I have 2 layouts once is default layout other one is layout-large-land.

Here is my Main Activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity {

@Optional
@InjectView(R.id.main_DrawerLayout)
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
@Optional
@InjectView(R.id.relativeInfo)
RelativeLayout relativeDraw;

private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (isTablet(getApplicationContext())) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    } else {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.inject(this);

    if (!isTablet(getApplicationContext())) {
        configureSlidingMenu();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.mipmap.menuicon);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_right_frame, new MenuRightFragment()).commit();
    } else {
        View v = new View(this);
        setBehindContentView(v);
        getSlidingMenu().setSlidingEnabled(false);
        getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_NONE);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.mipmap.usericontablet);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);

        if(findViewById(R.id.main_DrawerLayout) != null){
            drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.mipmap.infoicon, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
                @Override
                public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                    if (item != null && item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
                        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
                            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                        } else {
                            drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }

                public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }

                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
            };
            drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
            drawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    }
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new MainPageFragment()).commit();
}
```

When I run in tablet, activty main will be crash and give error by drawerLyout is null , relativeinfo is null and menu_frame is null.
Here is the error :

```
 Process: com.example packagename, PID: 20177
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo com.example packagename/com.example packagename.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d0090 (com.example packagename:id/menu_frame) for fragment LeftMenuFragment{420ff480 #1 id=0x7f0d0090}
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d0090 (com.example packagename:id/menu_frame) for fragment LeftMenuFragment{420ff480 #1 id=0x7f0d0090}
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:882)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1453)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5460)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: At the end of your code: There is     "getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new MainPageFragment()).commit();" Shoud it be in else clause after "getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);" ?

Comment: thank you for your response.This error made by my device. I closed landscape mode in my tablet and my layout folder name was "layout-large-land" so when I change the name to "layout -arge" it work fine.